# Converting Hasmap to JSONObject error in API 16

Tags: android

```
 HashMap<String,List> test=new HashMap<>();
 List<String> nn=new ArrayList<>();
 nn.add("jknlkn");
 nn.add("jijj");
 nn.add("ihohiol");
 test.put("gyi", nn);
 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
 System.out.println(new JSONObject(new HashMap(test)));
```

Logcat:

1. API 16 Device(Ice cream sandwich)

   06-21 21:07:19.952 23465-23465/com.miniapps.dolphinadmin I/System.out: {"gyi": "[jknlkn, jijj, ihohiol]" }

Wrong output

2. API 23 (Android M)

   06-21 21:07:19.952 23465-23465/com.miniapps.dolphinadmin I/System.out: { "gyi":[ "jknlkn", "jijj", "ihohiol" ]}

Correct output

My question is why it isnt working correctly in API 16?

Comment: Because using [wrap](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#wrap(java.lang.Object)) was added in API 19 (it fx checks for some basic class like collection and wrap it into JSONArray)... before that `{"gyi": "[jknlkn, jijj, ihohiol]" }` was correct output ... org.json is not a mapper API, so if you wana create complex JSON you shouldn't base on `JSONObject(Map)` ... or use different API/library

Comment: So can u please say me how do I achieve the correct output in API 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by any chance you are using GSON library in your code. You can use the below code achieve what you want.

```
HashMap<String,List> test=new HashMap<>();
 List<String> nn=new ArrayList<>();
 nn.add("jknlkn");
 nn.add("jijj");
 nn.add("ihohiol");
 test.put("gyi", nn);
 Gson gson = new Gson();
  String json = gson.toJson(test);
```

This will always give the expected output.

Comment: Oh! ya im using Gson too and it worked! Thanks a lot